# Observable not working with async await function in Doc reader

Tags: angular, async-await, rxjs, observable

I am trying to put await on Observable like below:

```js
    documentXFDFRetriever: async () => {
            const rows = await this.annotationsService.getAnnotations(this.userService.getCurrentDocumentId()).toPromise();
            console.log(rows);
            return rows.map(row => row.annotationNode);
          }
```

**My Service function:**

```js
    public getAnnotations(docId): Observable<Annotation[]> {
        const userId = this.userService.getCurrentUserId();
        const annotationsRef = collection(this.firestore, `annotations/${docId}/${userId}`);
        return collectionData(annotationsRef) as Observable<Annotation[]>;
    }
```

But it can't return rows on `documentXFDFRetriever` function.

I m sure something is missing here on the return observable.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the observable `toPromise` helper function waits for the observable to complete (or error) before actually resolving itself.

So to resolve this issue you can `take` the first emitted value from the `Observable` to complete it, before calling the `toPromise` function, like the following:

```js
// import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';

// by using `take` operator, the converted observable will be completed after emitting one value, then being converted to `Promise`.
const rows = await this.annotationsService.getAnnotations(this.userService.getCurrentDocumentId()).pipe(take(1)).toPromise();
```

**OR** if you are using RxJS 7, you can use the `firstValueFrom` helper function instead of `toPormise` one, to achieve the same thing.

For more information:
https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/to-promise

Comment: Working now :) Thanks for the detail info.

Answer (score 0):

Ironically, this exact confusion is why RxJS has deprecated `toPromise`. If you're using a newer version of RxJS, I would recommend `firstValueFrom` or `lastValueFrom`.

If you're using an older version of RxJS, you can use take(1) or first() to ensure the observable completes and resolves the promise.

```ts
documentXFDFRetriever: () => this.annotationsService.getAnnotations(
  this.userService.getCurrentDocumentId()
).pipe(
  map(rows => rows.map(row => row.annotationNode)),
  first() // Complete Observable after first emission
).toPromise();
```